# Encryption export compliance document in iOS app store

Tags: data-protection, encryption

I am using [encrypted core data](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data) (a wrapper of sqlcipher for core data) in my application in order to encrypt the database, and later before submitting the app to the appstore, I happened to notice that such encryptions require encryption export compliance document to be submitted in App Store. So while reading the export regulations in iTunes connect, it says:

> "If you distribute an app that uses, accesses, contains, implements, or incorporates encryption on Apple's App Store internationally, this is considered an export of encryption software, and is therefore subject to U.S. export and other country import compliance requirements."

Does this mean that the compliance document needs to be submitted only when the app is submitted in the store internationally and not needed when the app is intended for a specific country? I am just submitting the app for a specific country, so do I need to take steps to answer encryption questions and upload encryption export compliance document in App Store?